# Add click handler to parent of element by "title begins with"

Tags: jquery, parent, title

I want to add a handler that will change the background of some elements with a class of `controlButtonInline` when the great-grandparent of an element with a `title` that begins with `Name` is clicked.

So far I have this but the event never runs. I don't think that `ABC` is getting populated with an id that the second jQuery can recognise.

```js
var ABC = $('select[title^="Name"]')

$(ABC).parent().parent().parent().click(function() {
  $('.controlButtonInline').css({
    'background': 'black'
  });
});
```

Any help gratefully received!

------EDIT 1------

I still can't get this to work, here is more information if anyone doesn't mind looking. I want to enact the click handler by clicking on the top DIV (I've written id="unstableID" because in the program that I'm using that ID will constantly change) but I need to identify this element from the title of the descendent DIV.

```js
var ABC = $('select[title^="Name"]')

ABC.parent().parent().parent().click(function() {
  $('.controlButtonInline').css({
    'background': 'black'
  });
});
```

```css
controlButtonInline {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<DIV id="unstableID">
  <DIV>
    <DIV>
      <DIV title="Name is BI">
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>

<DIV class="controlButtonInline">Text
</DIV>
```

Comment: Your code seems ok, although you're double-wrapping your `ABC` jQuery object, and chained `parent()` calls should be replaced with `closest()`. If it's not working for you please edit the question to include a sample of your HTML so we can see an example of the problem

Comment: Shouldn’t it be two `parent()` calls?

Comment: I want three generations above the element that has that title so .parent().parent().parent() is the only solution I could think of

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I've added some more lines of code that should explain the issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML. The problem is because the element with the `title` attribute is a `div`, not a `select`. Fix that and the code works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22539627)

Comment: Fantastic, that works, thank you very much @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the element with the `title` attribute is a `div`, not a `select`. Fix the jQuery selector and the code works.

That being said, it's better practice to use `addClass()` over `css()` as it doesn't place an CSS logic in your JS file. Also note that you should avoid using chained `parent()` calls where possible. `closest()` is much better practice:

```js
var $ABC = $('div[title^="Name"]')

$ABC.closest('.great-grandparent').click(function() {
  $('.controlButtonInline').addClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.controlButtonInline {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red
}

.controlButtonInline.foo {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="unstableID" class="great-grandparent">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div title="Name is BI">Click me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="controlButtonInline">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ABC = $('select[title^="Name"]')

ABC.closest('.great-grandparent').click(function(){
  $('.controlButtonInline').css({
        'background': 'black'
    });
});
```

or

```
var ABC = $('select[title^="Name"]')

ABC.parents('.great-grandparent').click(function(){
      $('.controlButtonInline').css({
            'background': 'black'
        });
});
```

Comment: replace ".great-grandparent" selector with your desire name